# Spring MVC best way to populate drop down list - properties file?

Tags: file, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu, properties

I want to populate a drop down list and I do not want to keep going to the database.
I was thinking to have my country list or language list in a properties file.  That way I could read it in, and then assign that to a variable.  I could then return that through the ModelAndView type.

Is this a good approach?  I am not sure how else to store static data.  I do not want to keep it in a class because it will be harder to update it if there needs to be a change.

Comment: +1, excellent question.  Could also work for things like states/provinces.

Comment: how could this be done technically? Have one long huge property with all the country names? I understand in Spring 3 this can be read into the code using @Value.  I assume this should be a static call since we dont want this happening each and every single time....the whole read and assign....I am still wondering what the best approach is....how to read in static data? Can someone advise and also leave a code example. Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

got an answer!
If I got a list of countries or languages, anything static, I can have this in my spring context file:

```
<util:map id="countryList" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry key="CA" value="Canada"/>
    <entry key="US" value="United States"/>
    <entry key="PK" value="Pakistan"/>
    <entry key="UE" value="UAE"/>
</util:map>
```

etc.

I would inject country list in my ModelAndView (or I think you can even access it directly without putting it in ModelAndView cuz it's in the global Spring context)

and then render ${countryList} in my jsp do -


`<form:select path="country">` 
`<form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---"/>` 
`<form:options items="${countryList}" />`
 
`</form:select>`

The options field should automatically render.  That is the gyst of of, I am going to try this now!!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could as well store this data in the database and use a cache for example like [ehCache](http://ehcache.org/). As they are stored in a database they could be updated easily and the cache would avoid to go to the database every time you need this information.